# Debugging NSJSONSerialization memory leaks

Tags: ios, json, swift, memory-leaks, xcode-instruments

I am using [SwiftyJSON 2.3.0](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) for JSON parsing in my Swift 2.0 project:

```
extension NSData {
    func JSONDict() -> Dictionary<String, AnyObject>? {
        do {
            return try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(self, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0)) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
        } catch let error as NSError {
            DLog("NSData: error converting data to JSON: \n\(self.asString)\nerror: \n\(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }

}

class NetworkOperation {

    lazy var defaultCompletionHandler: NSURLSessionCompletionHandler = { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
        guard let s = self where !s.cancelled else {
            return
        }

        if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            switch httpResponse.statusCode {
                case 200..<300:
                    s.successResponse(data, response: response, error: error)

                // ...
            }
        } else {
            // ...
        }            
    }

    func successResponse(data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) {
        DLog("NetworkOperation: '\(name!)' finished")

        if let jsonDict = data.JSONDict() {
            let json = JSON(jsonDict)
            // process JSON
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, but my app seems to leak a lot of memory every time it parses JSON. I tried doing generational analysis using Instruments, and here is what it shows:

[image: Instruments screenshot]

It seems like `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` is the cause. Leaked chunks of memory, however, are `malloc_zone_malloc`/`malloc_zone_calloc` (i.e. not ARC-managed), so I cannot see reference counts.

**How do I proceed with the debugging of this issue?**

Comment: You certainly do have a lot of stuff in there: extension, lazy, [weak self], closure in a property, does all that make the lifetimes easier to understand?  [Brian Kernighan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Kernighan): *Everyone knows that debugging is twice as hard as writing a program in the first place. So if you're as clever as you can be when you write it, how will you ever debug it?* [Kent Beck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kent_Beck): *Do The Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work*.

Comment: @zaph yeah, I know, it is overly complex :) But I have an excuse that major part of this code is not authored by me and I haven't had time to refactor it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of this issue is a Swift 2.0 bug (see Xcode 7 [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc7_release_notes.html)):

"*Using switch against multiple types with as patterns may cause a memory leak. For example, avoid this kind of switch statement:*

```
switch x {
  case let a as A: ...
  case let b as B: ...
  case let c as C: ...
  default: ...
}
```

*Rewrite the code to use if let a = x as? A statements instead of switch. This pattern performs type checks that avoid the memory leak. (22587077)*"

Incidentally, this is exactly the type of switch statement SwiftyJSON uses internally. There is an open issue: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/issues/323

This bug has been fixed in Swift 2.1 (according to @zaph). For now, the solution is to replace the following code in `SwiftyJSON.swift`:

```
switch newValue {
    case let number as NSNumber:
        if number.isBool {
            _type = .Bool
        } else {
            _type = .Number
        }
        self.rawNumber = number
    case  let string as String:
        _type = .String
        self.rawString = string
    case  _ as NSNull:
        _type = .Null
    case let array as [AnyObject]:
        _type = .Array
        self.rawArray = array
    case let dictionary as [String : AnyObject]:
        _type = .Dictionary
        self.rawDictionary = dictionary
    default:
        _type = .Unknown
        _error = NSError(domain: ErrorDomain, code: ErrorUnsupportedType, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "It is a unsupported type"])
}
```

with:

```
if let number = newValue as? NSNumber {
    if number.isBool {
        _type = .Bool
    } else {
        _type = .Number
    }
    self.rawNumber = number
} else if let string = newValue as? String {
    _type = .String
    self.rawString = string
} else if let _ = newValue as? NSNull {
    _type = .Null
} else if let array = newValue as? [AnyObject] {
    _type = .Array
    self.rawArray = array
} else if let dictionary = newValue as? [String : AnyObject] {
    _type = .Dictionary
    self.rawDictionary = dictionary
} else {
    _type = .Unknown
    _error = NSError(domain: ErrorDomain, code: ErrorUnsupportedType, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "It is a unsupported type"])
}
```

(credit goes to [tehong](https://github.com/tehong))

Comment: Note: This has been fixed in Swift 2.1.